# deleting character - delete index or delete memory location

Tags: java, string

```
StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder(str);
s.deleteCharAt(0);
```

Let's say we have a string `"abcde"` and using the `deleteCharAt()` function, we delete the character `'c'`. does this function delete the memory location also. The character `'c'` is at index 2. After deleting the character, does it replace the character with empty space or does it delete the index and memory location?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is backed by an array, so, the contents of the array is shifted, so the memory location itself doesn't change, only what it references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `deleteCharAt` actually executes this code:

```
System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
count--;
```

Which means it copies the rest of the string to override the deleted character. So in your example, it'll copy "de" to override 'c', making it look like "abdee", then `count--` makes it finally "abde".

So yes, you can assume that it deletes the memory location, not just replaces it by an empty char.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so does that means if we have a string "peter" and we use the delete character function to delete the character 't' the result will be 'peer' not 'pe er'?

Comment: Exactly. It'll be peer not pe er. You can try it yourself actually.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you do that? I just clicked on the up arrow on your answer.

Comment: Can you help me with one question I have using this delete character method

Comment: There's a "correct" mark that you can check under the arrows. I can gladly help with that, but if it's a different question you'd better ask on a different thread.

Comment: Oh the green arrow, yes i clicked on it now

Comment: Yes, it's actually a different question. I need to know what's going on with my code? should I make a new question for that? Thanks

Comment: Yes please. Stackoverflows rules states that different questions should go into different threads.

Comment: Ok now I'm posting the question. Thanks

Comment: It said I have to wait for 90 minutes to ask a question. so, I'll post the question in just few minutes thanks

Comment: I posted the question. can you please help me with the question now thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Islan Hassan has said, the part of the string after the char to be deleted is copied back by one char in the internal char array which `StringBuilder` uses to store the string. However it doesn't shrink the size of the array, so using `deleteCharAt` in this fashion will not ever release any memory. Instead the capacity of the `StringBuilder` is maintained. Space for an extra char is now available at the end of the string in the `StringBuilder` which will be used on some subsequent insert or append operation.